# Is it yet possible to blueprint Concrete?

Tags: factorio

I'd like to know if it is somehow possible to include Concrete in a blueprint. When I select an area with my blueprint, the ground is ignored. Do i need to hold a special key, or is it just not possible (yet)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to concrete some empty piece of land (with no buildings on it) and then blueprint it.
Next use it as a regular blueprint (even under already built factories et al)

Comment: Ah, thanks. That should help. So there is no way to **include** it?

Comment: @O.Vollbrecht No, there is not. Frustratingly, it *used* to be included in blueprints, but an update (not sure which one) changed that.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>You need to ghost the concrete. Then they will be included.</strike>

When you make a blueprint for you can select "include tiles" and exclude everything else. That will make a blueprint for only the concrete tiles.

Comment: What do you mean by "ghost the concrete" ?  Thanks

Comment: @Roman hold shift while placing, Then you will place a ghost image for construction bots to finish laying down. It's handy for extending your inventory while expanding your base.

Comment: Note to Googlers, make sure you also tick **Include tiles** in the blueprint screen if you have selected tiles **and** any other sort of item in the blue print. e.g. walls, gun turrets.

Answer (score 5):

In 0.13 You can have blueprint containing both terrain and machines, you can just select whether you want to include only terrain, machines or both by the checkboxes.